# How to find Taint info for Nodes through kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have multiple questions for getting taint information.I know Taint info can be taken from here:  (View existing taints on which Taints exist on current nodes.)
`kubectl get nodes -o='custom columns=NodeName:.metadata.name,TaintKey:.spec.taints[].key,TaintValue:.spec.taints[].value,TaintEffect:.spec.taints[*].effect'`

- Above is as per documentation given in this link, but where is this being referenced from ? Where is this listed?`https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/`
- but how do I find that taint is under Spec. As per kubectl commands, "Taint" value only comes under "kubectl describe node" and not "kubectl get node -o yaml". File output is coming as below:

```
kubectl get node server.ec2.internal -o yaml > nodespecoutput.yaml
```

```yaml
    name: server.ec2.internal
          resourceVersion: "..."
          uid: 3a6be337-f45d-4d88-95de-ce3a727fc89b
        spec:
          providerID: aws:///us-east-1b/i-0ba5c3380ed5e423e
        status:
          addresses:
          - address: 172.24.16.207
            type: InternalIP
```

```
kubectl describe node server.ec2.internal -o yaml > nodespecoutputdesc.yaml
```

```yaml
volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 05 Jul 2022 16:17:44 -0600
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  server.ec2.internal
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Thu, 03 Nov 2022 19:57:02 -0600
```

- I can only find this documentation : (nothing here.)
  `https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#nodespec-v1-core`
- how do I find out(proof) that spec contains "taints", either some documentation , or some "--help" style documentation , or output for "-o yaml ", or output for "-o json"?

**I have tried using kubectl "get" and "describe".I have also tried understanding YAML structure, but it is not listed there, or I might be missing something.**

Answer (score 0):

A good way to understand the structure of Kubernetes' Resources is through the one-page [Kubernetes API Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/)

- Find the [Node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/#node-v1-core) Resource
- Then per your example, look under `spec` which is type [`NodeSpec`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/#nodespec-v1-core)
- See that `taints` is an array of [`Taint`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/#taint-v1-core)

Then, knowing that you can [`kubectl get {resource} --output`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/#output-options) various flavors (I prefer `jsonpath`), you can use e.g. the [`JSONPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) implementation used by Kubernetes (not the same as `JSONPath` elsewhere) to filter the output.

If the `JSONPath` filtering is insufficient, you can pipe the results into other tools e.g. [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

If you'd prefer to use YAML, you'll want to `--output=yaml` but `kubectl` includes no built-in processing of YAML output and so you'll want to use a tool like [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq).

You can also add `--v` (log level verbosity) to any `kubectl` command. `--v=6` (or above) should include the underlying Kubernetes API calls being made to effect the command.

Answer (score 0):

I will start by answering your second bullet point,

1. The values of `taints` are visible in both the described output and get YAML output.

> FYI, in the describe output, it will show the field as `Taints` and in
> the yamls, it shows as `taints`

. To see that, run the following commands :

```
# This is the YAML of node
kubectl get node <node-name> -oyaml > node-get-output.yaml 

# This is the describe output of node
kubectl describe node <node-name> > node-describe-output.yaml
```

Now, In the output of `get`, you will notice: (pasting a demo YAML)

```
spec:
  podCIDR: ....
  podCIDRs:
  - ...
  providerID: gce://.../us-central1-f/...
  taints:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: demo
    value: StackOverflow
```

And the `describe` output will look something like this:

```
Name:               ...
Roles:              ...
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
              
Annotations:        container.googleapis.com/instance_id: ...
                 
CreationTimestamp:  ...
Taints:             demo=StackOverflow:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
```

2. It is a concept of the kubernetes that for every Kubernetes object all the configuration stuff will go under `spec` section of the YAML, you can refer the documentation as well, taints also comes under it. You can also see it using the kubectl utility, its output contains all the attributes which comes under `spec`:

```
kubectl explain node.spec
```

Comment: explain command definitely helps in understanding ,but for some reason I don't get the same output as you do.I have updated my question with my output for reference.